# C# using System.Xaml missing assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm writing a C# Console Application that is targeted towards .Net 4.5. I want to use Xaml Services to save and read a List data structure to file. I'm using VS 2013 Pro.

The .net doc's say Xaml has been in .NET since 4.0(?) I have my projected targeted to 4.5, but even with 4.0, 4.5.1, 4.6, and 4.6.1... same missing assembly reference. I'm doing a

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xaml; // <-- this is getting the assembly error
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

But that is where the missing reference is getting the error...

I've used it before in Win Forms. It is that maybe it's excluded for console applications? Or am I missing something that Xaml Class depends on before using that assembly?

Comment: looks like a typo `System.Xmal` should be `System.Xaml`

Comment: or maybe `System.Xml` ?

Comment: Yes, was typo on post, System.Xaml but in my code, but not taking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you did not add a project reference to the assembly "System.Xaml.dll"? The Xaml functionality is not contained in the assemblies which are included in a new VS console project by default. (Right-Click on the "References" entry of the project, then select "Add References", then browse to "Framework" and look for System.Xaml, which refers to the dll of that name).

A namespace however does not necessarily correspond uniquely to an assembly, so you might require even more assemblies. If you know which types you need, you can browse the MSDN documentation for looking which assembly might still be required.

Comment: Thanks. After some looking, that is where it was.